# How do I compute a variable based on a specific logic in R?

Tags: r

Below is the code to reproduce the dataframe

```
df <- structure(list(master_id = c(100L, 100L, 102L, 102L, 600L, 600L, 
800L, 800L, 800L), vaccination_id = c(19682164L, 26761757L, 21051316L, 
26452487L, 20834063L, 26513056L, 20833333L, 26514589L, 26514501L
), vaccine_name = c("JSN", "PFR", "JSN", "MOD", "JSN", "MOD", 
"JSN", "PFR", "PFR"), vaccine_code = c(212L, 208L, 212L, 207L, 
212L, 207L, 212L, 208L, 208L), given_date = c("3/9/2021", "11/9/2021", 
"4/11/2021", "11/1/2021", "4/7/2021", "11/3/2021", "3/10/2021", 
"11/22/2021", "5/23/2022"), dose_number = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L
))
```

This is what my dataframe looks like:

```
master_id vaccination_id vaccine_name vaccine_code given_date dose_number
1       100       19682164          JSN          212   3/9/2021           1
2       100       26761757          PFR          208  11/9/2021           2
3       102       21051316          JSN          212  4/11/2021           1
4       102       26452487          MOD          207  11/1/2021           2
5       600       20834063          JSN          212   4/7/2021           1
6       600       26513056          MOD          207  11/3/2021           2
7       800       20833333          JSN          212  3/10/2021           1
8       800       26514589          PFR          208 11/22/2021           2
9       800       26514501          PFR          208  5/23/2022           3
```

This is the desired output. Essentially, I am trying to add a column that designates when a person first became boosted based on the following logic:
A person is boosted if they had any of the following vaccine combinations:

- 3 or more PFR type vaccines,
- 3 or more of type MOD,
- 3 or more of MOD, FPR vaccines,
- 2 or more of JSN vaccines
- 2 or more of JSN, FPR vaccines
- 2 or more of JSN, MOD vaccines

```
master_id vaccination_id vaccine_name vaccine_code given_date dose_number date_first_boosted
1       100       19682164          JSN          212   3/9/2021           1                   
2       100       26761757          PFR          208  11/9/2021           2          11/9/2021
3       102       21051316          JSN          212  4/11/2021           1                   
4       102       26452487          MOD          207  11/1/2021           2          11/1/2021
5       600       20834063          JSN          212   4/7/2021           1                   
6       600       26513056          MOD          207  11/3/2021           2          11/3/2021
7       800       20833333          JSN          212  3/10/2021           1                   
8       800       26514589          PFR          208 11/22/2021           2         11/22/2021
9       800       26514501          PFR          208  5/23/2022           3         11/22/2021
```

Comment: *3 or more of MOD, FPR vaccines* and *2 or more of JSN, FPR vaccines* should be *PFR*?

Comment: @AndreWildberg sorry it was a typo. It should be PFR, not FPR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cumsum()` to determine which date an individual fulfills the conditions.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(master_id) %>%
  mutate(date_first_boosted = if_else(
    cumsum(vaccine_name == "PFR") == 3 |
      cumsum(vaccine_name == "MOD") == 3 |
      cumsum(vaccine_name %in% c("MOD", "PFR")) == 3 |
      cumsum(vaccine_name == "JSN") == 2 |
      cumsum(vaccine_name %in% c("JSN", "PFR")) == 2 |
      cumsum(vaccine_name %in% c("JSN", "MOD")) == 2,
    given_date, NA
  )) %>%
  tidyr::fill(date_first_boosted) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 9 × 4
#   master_id vaccine_name given_date date_first_boosted
#       <int> <chr>        <chr>      <chr>             
# 1       100 JSN          3/9/2021   NA                
# 2       100 PFR          11/9/2021  11/9/2021         
# 3       102 JSN          4/11/2021  NA                
# 4       102 MOD          11/1/2021  11/1/2021         
# 5       600 JSN          4/7/2021   NA                
# 6       600 MOD          11/3/2021  11/3/2021         
# 7       800 JSN          3/10/2021  NA                
# 8       800 PFR          11/22/2021 11/22/2021        
# 9       800 PFR          5/23/2022  11/22/2021
```

Comment: Awesome! Your code works perfectly and it exactly what I needed. I only made slight adjustments to make it handle some of other cases I encountered in the data

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the date is sorted and there are **only** three vaccine_name, we can utilize the fact that first boosted date is the second vaccine date if one of the first two vaccine name is JSN. Otherwise, it is the third vaccine date.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(master_id)%>%
  mutate(date_first_boosted=ifelse("JSN" %in% head(vaccine_name,2),given_date[2],given_date[3]))

# A tibble: 9 x 7
# Groups:   master_id [4]
  master_id vaccination_id vaccine_name vaccine_code given_date dose_number date_first_boosted
      <int>          <int> <chr>               <int> <chr>            <int> <chr>             
1       100       19682164 JSN                   212 3/9/2021             1 11/9/2021         
2       100       26761757 PFR                   208 11/9/2021            2 11/9/2021         
3       102       21051316 JSN                   212 4/11/2021            1 11/1/2021         
4       102       26452487 MOD                   207 11/1/2021            2 11/1/2021         
5       600       20834063 JSN                   212 4/7/2021             1 11/3/2021         
6       600       26513056 MOD                   207 11/3/2021            2 11/3/2021         
7       800       20833333 JSN                   212 3/10/2021            1 11/22/2021        
8       800       26514589 PFR                   208 11/22/2021           2 11/22/2021        
9       800       26514501 PFR                   208 5/23/2022            3 11/22/2021
```

Comment: This was a great solution as well, but for some reason it didn't handle well cases where someone had taken a bunch of doses say like 4 or more of different kinds. But, just like every other code others have shared, I stole some of the syntax you used specifically the ```given_date[2]`` and used that elsewhere in my code. Thanks so much for your solution. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative that is a bit more explicit.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(given_date = mdy(given_date))
df %>%
  group_by(master_id) %>%
  arrange(given_date) %>%
  mutate(num_pfr = cumsum(vaccine_name == "PFR"),
         num_mod = cumsum(vaccine_name == "MOD"),
         num_mod_pfr = cumsum(vaccine_name %in% c("MOD", "PFR")),
         num_jsn = cumsum(vaccine_name == "JSN"),
         num_jsn_pfr = cumsum(vaccine_name %in% c("JSN", "PFR")),
         num_jsn_mod = cumsum(vaccine_name %in% c("JSN", "MOD"))) %>%
  mutate(boosted = case_when(num_pfr >= 3 ~ TRUE,
                             num_mod >= 3 ~ TRUE,
                             num_mod_pfr >= 3 ~ TRUE,
                             num_jsn >= 2 ~ TRUE,
                             num_jsn_pfr >= 2 ~ TRUE,
                             num_jsn_mod >= 2 ~ TRUE,
                             TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>%
  mutate(booster_date = min(given_date[boosted])) %>%
  select(master_id, boosted, given_date, booster_date)
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   master_id [4]
  master_id boosted given_date booster_date
      <int> <lgl>   <date>     <date>      
1       100 FALSE   2021-03-09 2021-11-09  
2       800 FALSE   2021-03-10 2021-11-22  
3       600 FALSE   2021-04-07 2021-11-03  
4       102 FALSE   2021-04-11 2021-11-01  
5       102 TRUE    2021-11-01 2021-11-01  
6       600 TRUE    2021-11-03 2021-11-03  
7       100 TRUE    2021-11-09 2021-11-09  
8       800 TRUE    2021-11-22 2021-11-22  
9       800 TRUE    2022-05-23 2021-11-22
```

Comment: You could re-arrange the output to make it look like what the OP requests.

Comment: Awesome! Your code works perfectly, and handle all cases well, but I chose @DarrenTsai as the answer mainly because it was shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works with your data set. Included an `arrange` if the *dose_number* is not in the right order.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  arrange(master_id, dose_number) %>% 
  mutate(date_first_boosted = if_else(
           all(grepl("PFR|MOD", vaccine_name)) & 
           n() >= 3 & 
           row_number() >= 3, given_date[3], ""), 
         date_first_boosted = if_else(
           any(grepl("JSN", vaccine_name)) & 
           n() >= 2 & 
           row_number() >= 2, given_date[2], ""), .by = master_id)
  master_id vaccination_id vaccine_name vaccine_code given_date dose_number
1       100       19682164          JSN          212   3/9/2021           1
2       100       26761757          PFR          208  11/9/2021           2
3       102       21051316          JSN          212  4/11/2021           1
4       102       26452487          MOD          207  11/1/2021           2
5       600       20834063          JSN          212   4/7/2021           1
6       600       26513056          MOD          207  11/3/2021           2
7       800       20833333          JSN          212  3/10/2021           1
8       800       26514589          PFR          208 11/22/2021           2
9       800       26514501          PFR          208  5/23/2022           3
  date_first_boosted
1                   
2          11/9/2021
3                   
4          11/1/2021
5                   
6          11/3/2021
7                   
8         11/22/2021
9         11/22/2021
```

Comment: Awesome! Your code works, but it didn't handle some of the cases. But I stole some ideas from it and used them in combination with some of the code others have posted below. I greatly appreciate your help